# Подсветка кода в комментарии рястягивается

Tags: дефект, дизайн, комментарии, блок-кода

Нашел [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516981/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-materi) где подсветка кода в комментариях несколько слетела:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

System:

- chrome - 112.0.5615.137 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Видимо, [это](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347630/339911). Да, инлайн код с пробелами так себя ведёт. По месту подправил. А вот [BR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361250/339911) непосредственно по коду в комментариях.

Comment: Да просто не нужно постить блоки кода в комментарии. Тем более, что все дополнения к вопросу должны быть в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо)

Comment: @insolor тем не менее, оно в FF вроде как не проявляется. Бага хрома.